# How to prevent php fopen from following symlinks

Tags: php, fopen, symlink, race-condition

I want to open a file in PHP while making sure that I don't follow any symlinks in the process.
In my specific case, there is a high risk of a race condition being exploited, **so just using `is_link()` to check the path before opening it won't solve the problem.**

`fopen()` seems not to support file creation/status flags (like `O_NOFOLLOW`) and after a few hours of searching, I wasn't able to find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't a lock with ```flock()``` solve your race condition?

Comment: The risk of a race condition does not originate from a PHP script but from a different (untrusted) application running inside a docker container (I could have been more clear on that). The container has a shared directory with the host, the PHP script (which is running on the host) should be able to read certain files in this directory, but not follow symlinks since they could point to files outside the directory.